# How to call a request to a server with period and send it again if response was invalid?

Tags: c++, qt, c++11, network-programming, qt5

I'm writing a simple client for a web service for my personal training. And I decided to do it with Qt. I'm using version 5.7. I managed to overcome troubles with sending and receiving requests from a server. But there is still a problem.

I have a slot `on_scanButton_click()` which, depending on what radio button is checked calls some request to a server. My problem is how to send another request to a server after first one with a period so that I could check if response_code in valid and I can call separate window for it.

This is my mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "networkmanager.h"
#include "commentdialog.h"
#include "rescanfiledialog.h"
#include "filebrowser.h"
#include "program_exceptions.h"
#include "overlaywidget.h"

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <regex>


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget* parent) :
    QMainWindow{parent} {
    ui.setupUi(this);

    ui.fileRadioButton->setFixedWidth(100);
    ui.urlRadioButton->setFixedWidth(100);
    ui.searchRadioButton->setFixedWidth(100);

    ui.stringFormater->setFixedSize(500, 30);
    ui.stringFormater->setPlaceholderText("No file selected");
    ui.uploadButton->setFixedHeight(30);

    ui.scanButton->setFixedSize(120, 50);
    ui.rescanButton->setFixedSize(120, 50);
    ui.commentButton->setFixedSize(120, 50);
}


void MainWindow::changeEvent(QEvent* e) {
    QMainWindow::changeEvent(e);

    switch (e->type()) {

        case QEvent::LanguageChange:
            ui.retranslateUi(this);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_scanButton_clicked() {
    NetworkManager* network_manager{new NetworkManager};
    QString input_string = ui.stringFormater->text();

    try {

        if (ui.fileRadioButton->isChecked()) {

            if (std::regex_match(input_string.toStdString(), std::regex("^(.*/)([^/]*)$"))) {

                network_manager->scanFileRequest(input_string);

            } else {
                throw InvalidFilePathException();
            }

        } else if (ui.urlRadioButton->isChecked()) {

            if (std::regex_match(input_string.toStdString(),
                             std::regex("^(ht{2}ps?:\\/{2})?(w{3}\\.)?([^:\\/\\.\\s]+)\\.([^:\\/\\.\\s]+)$"))) {
                network_manager->scanUrlRequest(input_string);

            } else {
                throw InvalidUrlNameException();
            }

        } else if (ui.searchRadioButton->isChecked()) {

            if (!std::regex_match(input_string.toStdString(), std::regex("([^:\\/\\.\\s]+)\\.([^:\\/\\.\\s]+)$"))) {

                if (!std::regex_match(input_string.toStdString(), std::regex("^(([0-9]{1,3})\\.){3}([0-9]{1,3})$"))) {
                    throw InvalidIpAddressException();

                } else {
                    network_manager->retrieveIpReportRequest(input_string);
                }

                throw InvalidDomainNameException();

            } else {
                network_manager->retrieveDomainReportRequest(input_string);
            }
        }

    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        QString exception_message{ex.what()};
        QMessageBox::warning(this, "Warning", exception_message);
    }

    ui.stringFormater->clear();
}


void MainWindow::on_fileRadioButton_clicked() {
    ui.stringFormater->setPlaceholderText("No file selected");
    ui.uploadButton->setText("Choose File");
    ui.scanButton->setText("Scan it!");
    ui.stringFormater->clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_urlRadioButton_clicked() {
    ui.stringFormater->setPlaceholderText("http://example.com");
    ui.uploadButton->setText("Enter URL");
    ui.scanButton->setText("Scan it!");
    ui.stringFormater->clear();
}

void MainWindow::on_searchRadioButton_clicked() {
    ui.stringFormater->setPlaceholderText("hash, URL, domain, IP address...");
    ui.uploadButton->setText("Enter Term");
    ui.scanButton->setText("Search it!");
    ui.stringFormater->clear();
}


void MainWindow::on_uploadButton_clicked() {
    if (ui.fileRadioButton->isChecked()) {
        FileBrowser* file_browser{new FileBrowser(this)};
        file_browser->exec();

        ui.stringFormater->setText(file_browser->getFilePath());
        file_browser->setFilePath("");
    }
}


void MainWindow::on_rescanButton_clicked() {
    RescanFileDialog* rescan_file_doalog{new RescanFileDialog(this)};
    rescan_file_doalog->exec();
}


void MainWindow::on_commentButton_clicked() {
    CommentDialog* comment_dialog{new CommentDialog(this)};
    comment_dialog->exec();
}
```

Here goes networkmanager.h.

```
#ifndef NETWORKMANAGER_H
#define NETWORKMANAGER_H

#include <QtNetwork>


class NetworkManager : public QObject {

    Q_OBJECT

private:

    QString api_address{"https://www.virustotal.com/vtapi/v2"};
    QByteArray api_key{"API KEY HERE"};
    QNetworkAccessManager* network_manager{new QNetworkAccessManager(this)};

    static QJsonObject json_response;

public:

    explicit NetworkManager() {
        connect(network_manager, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(requestFinished(QNetworkReply*)));
    }

    virtual ~NetworkManager() = default;

    void scanFileRequest(const QString&);
    void rescanFileRequest(const QString&);
    void retrieveFileReportRequest(const QString&);

    void scanUrlRequest(const QString&);
    void retrieveUrlReportRequest(const QString&);

    void retrieveIpReportRequest(const QString&);
    void retrieveDomainReportRequest(const QString&);
    void makeCommentRequest(const QString&, const QString&);

    const static QJsonObject getJsonResponse() {
        return json_response;
    }

private slots:

    void requestFinished(QNetworkReply*);
};


#endif // NETWORKMANAGER_H
```

And networkmanager.cpp.

```
#include "networkmanager.h"
#include "responses.h"
#include "status_codes.h"
#include "program_exceptions.h"

#include <QMessageBox>
#include <QTimer>


QJsonObject NetworkManager::json_response{};


void NetworkManager::scanFileRequest(const QString& absolute_file_path) {
    const QFileInfo file_info{absolute_file_path};
    QHttpMultiPart* multi_part{new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType)};

    QHttpPart api_key_part{};
    api_key_part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"apikey\""));
    api_key_part.setBody(api_key);

    QHttpPart file_part{};
    QMimeDatabase db{};
    QMimeType mime_message{db.mimeTypeForFile(file_info)};
    file_part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant(mime_message.name()));
    file_part.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader,
                    QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\"" + file_info.fileName() + "\""));

    QFile* file{new QFile(absolute_file_path)};

    try {

        if (!file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly)) {
            throw FileDoesNotExistException();
        }

    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        QMessageBox message_box{QMessageBox::Warning, "Warning", QObject::tr(ex.what()),
                            QMessageBox::NoButton, 0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint};

        message_box.exec();
    }

    file_part.setBodyDevice(file);
    file->setParent(multi_part);

    multi_part->append(api_key_part);
    multi_part->append(file_part);

    QNetworkRequest request{QUrl{api_address + "/file/scan"}};
    network_manager->post(request, multi_part);
}


void NetworkManager::rescanFileRequest(const QString& resource) {
    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("resource", resource);

    QUrl post_params{};
    post_params.setQuery(query_set);

    QByteArray post_data{post_params.toEncoded(QUrl::RemoveFragment)};
    post_data.remove(0, 1);

    QNetworkRequest request{QUrl{api_address + "/file/rescan"}};
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    network_manager->post(request, post_data);
}


void NetworkManager::retrieveFileReportRequest(const QString& resource) {
    QUrl url{api_address + "/file/report"};

    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("resource", resource);

    url.setQuery(query_set.query());
    QNetworkRequest request{url};

    network_manager->get(request);
}


void NetworkManager::scanUrlRequest(const QString& url) {
    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("url", url);

    QUrl post_params{};
    post_params.setQuery(query_set);

    QByteArray post_data{post_params.toEncoded(QUrl::RemoveFragment)};
    post_data.remove(0, 1);

    QNetworkRequest request{QUrl{api_address + "/url/scan"}};
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    network_manager->post(request, post_data);
}


void NetworkManager::retrieveUrlReportRequest(const QString& resource) {
    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("resource", resource);

    QUrl post_params{};
    post_params.setQuery(query_set);

    QByteArray post_data{post_params.toEncoded(QUrl::RemoveFragment)};
    post_data.remove(0, 1);

    QNetworkRequest request{QUrl{api_address + "/url/report"}};
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    network_manager->post(request, post_data);
}


void NetworkManager::retrieveIpReportRequest(const QString& ip) {
    QUrl url{api_address + "/ip-address/report"};

    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("ip", ip);

    url.setQuery(query_set.query());
    QNetworkRequest request{url};

    network_manager->get(request);
}


void NetworkManager::retrieveDomainReportRequest(const QString& domain) {
    QUrl url{api_address + "/domain/report"};

    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("domain", domain);

    url.setQuery(query_set.query());
    QNetworkRequest request{url};

    network_manager->get(request);
}


void NetworkManager::makeCommentRequest(const QString& resource, const QString& comment) {
    QUrlQuery query_set{};
    query_set.addQueryItem("apikey", api_key);
    query_set.addQueryItem("resource", resource);
    query_set.addQueryItem("comment", comment);

    QUrl post_params{};
    post_params.setQuery(query_set);

    QByteArray post_data{post_params.toEncoded(QUrl::RemoveFragment)};
    post_data.remove(0, 1);

    QNetworkRequest request{QUrl{api_address + "/comments/put"}};
    request.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");

    network_manager->post(request, post_data);
}


void NetworkManager::requestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
    try {
        http_status_code_t server_reply{static_cast<http_status_code_t>(
                                        reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt())};

        if (server_reply == OK) {
            QJsonObject json_object = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
            response_code_t response_code{static_cast<response_code_t>(json_object["response_code"].toInt())};
            std::string verbose_msg{json_object["verbose_msg"].toString().toStdString()};

            if (response_code == ITEM_IS_PRESENT) {
                json_response = json_object;
                qDebug() << json_response;

            } else if (response_code == ITEM_IS_STILL_IN_QUEUE) {
                throw RequestStillInQueueException(verbose_msg);

            } else if (response_code == ITEM_DOES_NOT_EXIST) {
                throw ItemDoesNotExistException(verbose_msg);

            } else {
                throw UnknownResponseCodeException();
            }

        } else if (server_reply == API_REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
            throw PublicAPIRequestRateExceededException();

        } else if (server_reply == FORBIDDEN) {
            throw ForbiddenException();

        } else {
            throw UnknownHttpStatusCodeException();
        }

    } catch (std::exception& ex) {
        QMessageBox message_box{QMessageBox::Warning, "Warning", QObject::tr(ex.what()),
                            QMessageBox::NoButton, 0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint};

        message_box.exec();
    }
}
```

So the question is where i have to put my QTimer, which will send `retrieveXXXXRequest()` function every 15 seconds till it gets response code what I need.

This is a link on github for more deep understanding.

https://github.com/lieroz/VirusTotalClient/tree/develop

Answer (score 0):

So the answer was very easy. I will post a solution here.
just changed some lines in networkmanager.cpp in requestFinished function.

```
void NetworkManager::requestFinished(QNetworkReply* reply) {
try {
    http_status_code_t server_reply{static_cast<http_status_code_t>(
                                        reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute).toInt())};

    if (server_reply == OK) {
        QJsonObject json_object = QJsonDocument::fromJson(reply->readAll()).object();
        response_code_t response_code{static_cast<response_code_t>(json_object["response_code"].toInt())};
        std::string verbose_msg{json_object["verbose_msg"].toString().toStdString()};

        if (response_code == ITEM_IS_PRESENT) {
            qDebug() << json_object;

            if (verbose_msg == "Scan finished, information embedded") {

                auto antiviruses = json_object["scans"].toObject().keys();
                auto values = json_object["scans"].toObject();

                for (auto antivirus : antiviruses) {
                    qDebug() << antivirus;

                    auto keys = values.value(antivirus).toObject().keys();

                    for (auto key : keys) {
                        qDebug() << key << " : " << values.value(antivirus).toObject().value(key);
                    }
                }

                return;
            }

            QTimer::singleShot(15000, this, [=]{
                retrieveFileReportRequest(json_object["resource"].toString());
            });

        } else {
            qDebug() << json_object;
            QTimer::singleShot(15000, this, [=]{
                retrieveFileReportRequest(json_object["resource"].toString());
            });
        }

    } else if (server_reply == API_REQUEST_LIMIT_EXCEEDED) {
        throw PublicAPIRequestRateExceededException();

    } else if (server_reply == FORBIDDEN) {
        throw ForbiddenException();

    } else {
        throw UnknownHttpStatusCodeException();
    }

} catch (std::exception& ex) {
    QMessageBox message_box{QMessageBox::Warning, "Warning", QObject::tr(ex.what()),
                            QMessageBox::NoButton, 0, Qt::FramelessWindowHint};

    message_box.exec();
}
```

}